# Failed to stateless autoconfiguration in ubuntu 14.04 without Network Manager

Tags: ubuntu, networking, configuration, ubuntu-14.04, ipv6

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I want to configure my network in manual mode so I remove network-manager. After that, I'm successful in configure my network with the address of IPv4 and IPv6 global static.

In file /etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 static
address a:b:c:d::
netmask 64
```

My other configurations :

```
accept_ra = 2 
forwarding = 1
```

However, I didn't have a chance with the address IPv6 global in mode stateless autoconfiguration.

In file /etc/network/interface:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

I can't get the address IPv6.

As a reminder, everything works fine with network-manager.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. With my configuration, it should be work well. But when I try to restart the network in ubuntu 14.04 with the command :

```
ifdown eth0 && ifup -v eth0
```

The command ifup always set accept_ra = 1 with :

```
systcl -q -e -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=1
```

Accept_ra = 1 doesn't work with forwarding = 1. 
To prevent this error, I suggest to use other way to restart the interface in ubuntu 14.04.